# plpgsql dynamic math/comparison operator calculation?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to figure out how to do arbitrary calculations in a function and update a true/false variable accordingly:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conditions;

CREATE TABLE conditions(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    val_1 INT NOT NULL,
    operator_1 TEXT,
    val_2 INT,
    comparison_operator TEXT NOT NULL,
    val_3 INT NOT NULL,
    operator_2 TEXT,
    val_4 INT,
    current_state BOOL,
    CONSTRAINT c1 CHECK ((val_2 IS NULL AND operator_1 IS NULL) OR (val_2 IS NOT NULL AND operator_1 IS NOT NULL)),
    CONSTRAINT c2 CHECK ((val_4 IS NULL AND operator_2 IS NULL) OR (val_4 IS NOT NULL AND operator_2 IS NOT NULL))
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_calculation()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN   
/*
    UPDATE conditions
    SET current_state = ...???
*/
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER calculate
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON conditions
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE do_calculation();

INSERT INTO conditions (val_1, comparison_operator, val_3) VALUES (1, '>', 2);
INSERT INTO conditions (val_1, operator_1, val_2, comparison_operator, val_3) VALUES (1, '+', 3, '>', 2);
INSERT INTO conditions (val_1, operator_1, val_2, comparison_operator, val_3, operator_2, val_4) VALUES (1, '+', 3, '=', 2, '*', 2);
UPDATE conditions SET val_1 = 3 WHERE id = 1;


SELECT * FROM conditions;
```

But how do I do the actual calculation in the do_calculation() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to update the table in the trigger function. Set the column of the `NEW` record and declare the trigger as `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`. Use [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_calculation()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN   
    EXECUTE concat(
        'SELECT ', 
        NEW.val_1, NEW.operator_1, NEW.val_2, 
        NEW.comparison_operator, 
        NEW.val_3 , NEW.operator_2 , NEW.val_4)
    INTO NEW.current_state;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER calculate
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON conditions
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE do_calculation();
```

Note that this approach is potentially prone to SQL-injection attacks. You can add some checks on text columns like `CHECK(operator_1 in ('+', '-', '*', '/'))` etc. to protect the table.